# Installed Windows before Ubuntu, both in BIOS mode, but GRUB install failed

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

Let me start by saying I've been trying to get it to work for 2 days, and that I've read a lot. The answer could be extremely obvious but I need someone to point it out.

I was trying to dual boot Windows and Ubuntu (yes, I followed a guide, but I don't remember which one) when the Grub install failed. So I aborted and kept tinkering with my disk configuration with no luck.

I tried Boot Repair from a CD in UEFI mode and that didn't work. Note that I can boot Windows fine in both EFI and UEFI mode.

Here are the steps I took:

1. Booted the Ubuntu GNOME installer in BIOS mode (fast boot disabled and CSM enabled.)
2. Formatted the entire disk in GParted.
3. Here is the configuration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0roG.jpg

The first 100 MB partition I flagged 'boot' and 'esp'. The 10 MB one is bios_grub. The 90 MB space is just in case I need it in the future.

The 8GB volume is SWAP. The first 250GB volume is where Linux is installed. It is EXT4. The second is also EXT4, but nothing is installed there. The rest are the various Windows partitions.

4. Partitioned my disk in various partitions for Ubuntu and Windows.
5. Booted Windows disk in BIOS mode and installed.
6. Booted Ubuntu installer and installed.
7. Grub install failed.

Here is my latest attempt at boot-repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/11314742/

In this attempt I tried to do a manual install to SDA1, with the overall bootloader install to SDA, if I remember correctly.

Where should I go from here? Should I erase all Ubuntu partitions and try again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First, your Windows installation, at least, is in EFI mode (aka UEFI mode; UEFI is just EFI 2.x), not in BIOS mode, as your question's title claims. That said, there is evidence of a BIOS-mode Linux boot loader, so you probably either installed Linux in BIOS mode initially or ran Boot Repair at least once in BIOS mode; but there's also evidence of an EFI-mode Linux boot loader.

Second, have you disabled the *Windows* "Fast Startup" (aka "Hybrid Boot") feature? If not, do so, as described [here.](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/6320-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-8-a.html) Note that this feature is *entirely separate* from the firmware's "fast start" (or similarly-named) feature. The Windows feature can cause corruption of partitions shared between Windows and Ubuntu, including the critical [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition), which holds EFI-mode boot loaders.

Third, and at least as important, there are problems with your partition table:

- Your `/dev/sda1` is identified as your ESP in your partition table, but it holds an ext4 filesystem. This is unusual bordering on invalid. The ESP must normally contain a FAT filesystem. It looks like you erred in setting up your partitions, and re-allocated the ESP to be your Linux `/boot` partition.
- Your `/dev/sda7` is FAT and holds files that would normally be on an ESP, but is marked as an ordinary FAT/NTFS volume.

The appropriate fix is to re-mark `/dev/sda1` as a Linux partition and `/dev/sda7` as an ESP. You can do this with GParted or `parted` by removing the "boot flag" from `/dev/sda1` and adding the "boot flag" to `/dev/sda7`; or in `gdisk` by changing the type code of `/dev/sda1` to 8300 and of `/dev/sda7` to EF00. This fix will probably not be enough to restore your system to bootability, but it may be a necessary prerequisite, and it's certainly necessary for safety.

As to fixing your problem, *after* you both disable Fast Startup and fix your partition type code issues, try re-running Boot Repair. Be sure to boot it in EFI mode. It was booted that way when you ran it to generate the output you've shown. Typically, you must select the boot option that includes "UEFI" in the description.

If Boot Repair doesn't work, try using a USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) It should enable you to boot your Linux installation, with one caveat: Because you've got a separate `/boot` partition, you may need to highlight your kernel, hit F2 or Insert twice, and add `ro root=/dev/sda4` to get it to boot correctly. (OTOH, this might not be necessary; it looks like you've got both a kernel on `/dev/sda4` and a separate `/boot` partition.) If rEFInd can start your system, you can either try to manually install GRUB (using `grub-install`) or install the rEFInd PPA or Debian package.

An alternative: Instead of attempting to repair your installation, you can try re-installing. You'll still need to disable Fast Startup in Windows, but once you do that, delete `/dev/sda1` through `/dev/sda5`, fix the type code on `/dev/sda7`, create new partitions (one for `/` and one for swap should be sufficient, but you can optionally create more), and install. Be sure to boot the installer in EFI mode; *do not* attempt a BIOS-mode installation. (Drop to a shell and look for the `/sys/firmware/efi` directory. If it's present, you've booted in EFI mode; but if it's absent, you've booted in BIOS mode.)